C++ Resource manager implementation: unique_ptr store in different places inside a class (vector and map)
I'm just a beginner in general. I'm trying to implement a resource manager for games. I want to preserve order of insertion (like layers in tilemap you want to render layer by layer, not shuffle) and also be able to get data by a name, so I have both unordered_map and vector inside a class call resource. And it works like expected
    template<typename T>
    using umap_str = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>>;

    template<typename T>
    using vec_sptr = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>;
    template<typename T>
    struct resource
    {
        inline static std::size_t _max_id; //inline to not have to init out of line
        umap_str<T> _map;
        vec_sptr<T> _vec;
    };
    template<typename... RsrcTs>
    struct resource_manager
    {
        template<typename T>
        using rsrc_t = resource<T>;

        std::tuple<rsrc_t<RsrcTs>...> storage;

        template<typename RsrcT>
        inline vec_sptr<RsrcT>& get_vec() {return std::get<rsrc_t<RsrcT>>(storage)._vec;};
        template<typename RsrcT>
        inline umap_str<RsrcT>& get_map() {return std::get<rsrc_t<RsrcT>>(storage)._map;};


        template<typename RsrcT>
        inline std::size_t& get_maxid() {return std::get<rsrc_t<RsrcT>>(storage)._max_id;};

        template<typename RsrcT>
        std::optional<std::shared_ptr<RsrcT>> get(std::string&& name)
        {
            auto& to_get = get_map<RsrcT>();
            if (!to_get.contains(name)) return std::nullopt;
            else return to_get.at(name);
        };
        // add resource with a name, or with an existing shared_ptr //
        template<typename RsrcT>
        std::shared_ptr<RsrcT> add(std::string&& custom_name = "")
        {
            static_assert(contains<RsrcT, RsrcTs...>().value, "resource type not in resource declaration");
            
            std::shared_ptr<RsrcT> new_resource = std::make_shared<RsrcT>();
            
            if (custom_name.empty()) 
                get_map<RsrcT>().insert({std::to_string(get_maxid<RsrcT>()), new_resource});
            else
            {
                if (get_map<RsrcT>().contains(custom_name))
                {
                    std::cout << custom_name << "currently in use, using id instead";
                    get_map<RsrcT>().insert({std::to_string(get_maxid<RsrcT>()), new_resource});
                }
                else get_map<RsrcT>().insert({custom_name, new_resource});
            };
    
            get_vec<RsrcT>().push_back(new_resource);

            get_maxid<RsrcT>()++;
            
            return new_resource;
        };
        
        template<typename RsrcT>
        std::shared_ptr<RsrcT> add(std::shared_ptr<RsrcT> arg, std::string&& custom_name = "")
        {
            static_assert(contains<RsrcT, RsrcTs...>().value, "resource type not in resource declaration");
            
            if (custom_name.empty()) 
                get_map<RsrcT>().insert({std::to_string(get_maxid<RsrcT>()), arg});
            else
            {
                if (get_map<RsrcT>().contains(custom_name))
                {
                    std::cout << custom_name << "currently in use, using id instead";
                    get_map<RsrcT>().insert({std::to_string(get_maxid<RsrcT>()), arg});
                }
                else get_map<RsrcT>().insert({custom_name, arg});
            };

            get_vec<RsrcT>().push_back(arg);

            get_maxid<RsrcT>()++;
            return arg;
        };
    };

----- I can smell that this approach may not be efficient and intuitive (maybe).
Now I want to try storing data with unique_ptr. How should I implement that. I know that I can't keep more than 1 copy of each, so i'm thinking of storing raw pointers (in the map or in the vec).
Any insights and recommendations would be much appriciated.

non owning pointers can be raw.

The owner of the data should hold the unique_ptr. The other part, just being an index, can use a non-owning raw pointer.

I have double-stored smart pointers in a fashion similar to what you're doing, but that may be an old mindset. How big are your vectors?
With modern hardware, searching a vector vs. doing a lookup in a hash map may not be significantly slower. I'd set up a test. Of course, you know the nature of your data, and I don't.
Regardless -- are you having performance issues using the shared_ptrs? Why do you want to switch to unique_ptr? I think what you're doing is fine.

Mainly for educational purpose. I want to achieve things in different ways. Performance for now is fine, but I don't think the nature of shared ptr is suitable, cause logically the manager is the only owner of the data
